# clustering correlation matrix of two dataset with same matrix ordering

Tags: r

I have two datasets of the triangular correlation matrix. I want to first use type='upper' and type='lower' to combine the two. Then order='hcluster' one dataset and order the other dataset with the ordering of the previous dataset.

```
library(randcorr)
library(corrplot)
vars <- LETTERS[1:10]
df1 <- randcorr(10)
dimnames(df1) <- list(vars, vars)
df2 <- randcorr(10)
dimnames(df2) <- list(vars, vars)

res1<- cor(df1)
res2<- cor(df2)

corrplot(res1, type="upper", method="color",  
     tl.cex=1, 
     tl.col = "black", 
     diag=FALSE,
     sig.level = 0.05, 
     order='hclust',
     insig = "blank",  
     number.cex=0.2)

corrplot(res2, type="lower", method="color",
     tl.cex=1,
     tl.col = "black", 
     diag=FALSE,
     sig.level = 0.05, 
     order="hclust", 
     insig = "blank",  
     number.cex=0.2) 

par(mfrow=c(1,1))
corrplot(res1, method = "color", type = "upper", tl.cex = 0.75, diag=FALSE,
     tl.col = "black", insig = "blank",  order='hclust', 
     number.cex = 0.75, tl.pos = "lt", tl.srt = 45)
   
corrplot(res2, method = "color", type = "lower", add = TRUE, tl.cex = 0.75, diag=FALSE,
     tl.col = "black", insig = "blank", tl.pos = "n", cl.pos = "n",
     number.cex = 0.75, tl.srt = 45)
```

Comparing to the plots I generated separately, I am not sure it is the correct way to put them together. Because I am not sure the second matrix is aligned with the cluster of the first matrix. Can anyone help fix and explain this?

Comment: In order to combine two matrices, they must have the same number of columns/rows in their correlation matrices and they should include the same variables. If that is so, they cannot be of different dimensions. Your code has missing commas between arguments and you do not correctly specify the `p.mat` matrix. Also "hcluster" is not a valid option for the `order=` argument. If you want more specific advice, provide reproducible data using `dput()`. The `iris` data set comes with R and could be used as an example or the `mtcars` data set used in the examples on the `corrplot` manual page.

Comment: The problem you mentioned is fixed.

Comment: The `cor.mtest()` function returns a list of 3 matrices. You need to specify which one you want in the `p.mat=` argument.

Comment: I edit the question, now it would be more clear

Comment: You need to change `res1` and `res2` to `df1` and `df2` to get the new code to work. If you put `dev.new()` between the two new plot commands, you will get each plot in a separate window. The order of the rows/columns is different because the cluster analysis of two different matrices is different so you cannot combine them on a single plot. If you delete the `order="hclust` from both plot commands, you will get the original matrix order, but that only helps if the variables are the same in both matrices. Otherwise you need to plot them separately.

Comment: Sorry, I missed two lines when I copy and paste. res1<- cor(df1) and res2<- cor(df2). I fixed it.

Comment: I knew it is impossible to hclust at the same time for both plots given a different array of the matrix. This is why I want to hclust one plot and retrieve the array of the matrix and apply that matrix to another plot. The second plot doesn't have to hclust. In this way, it is possible to combine them together

Comment: The two matrices must have the same variables. Plot the first matrix and record the order of the columns. Then reorder the columns of the second data set to match it. If you are working with a correlation matrix, reordering is more challenging since you have to re-order the rows and the columns. The corrplot function seems the lose the space for the diagonal when you plot upper and lower triangles separately.

Comment: Thank you. I have solved the problem by using CorReorder